# std::sort of vector of struct sorted by field where all are zeros causing different results for different length of vector

Tags: c++, std

Hello I have this piece of code for sorting vector. Basically sorting vector of structure where at the start all elements of vector has score equal to 0. I thought that if all elements equals score 0 sort will keep for multiple sort but only when  **uint8_t length = 17;** is under 17. It is probably caused by implementation of sort that 16 is somehow important for sorting.

reference code here https://www.onlinegdb.com/C_wj9_87L

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t index;
    uint8_t score;
} test;

uint8_t length = 17;

int main()
{
    std::vector<test> vec;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        vec.push_back({i, 0});
    }
    
    for (uint8_t j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const test &m1, const test &m2) {
           return m1.score > m2.score; 
        });
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            std::cout << (int)vec[i].index << ", ";
        }    
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Result with uint8_t length = 17;

```
8, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 
9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
0, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,
```

#### Result with uint8_t length = 16;

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
```

Do you know what is going wrong here ?

Expected result is always same sort so indexes will remain its position.

Comment: If you need a stable sort, use `stable_sort`. Plain sort isn't required to be stable.

Comment: Yeah the case is not index. Index is just for the output. The question is about why vector of length 16 is always sorted in same order whlie vector of size 17 is not. Score is 0 on purpose.

Comment: @DanielLazar Nothing is going wrong, both vectors are sorted. The likely reason is a different algorithm being used when the vector size is over a certain threshold.

Comment: Related: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare

Comment: Note that `std::sort` implementations are typically based on hybrid sorting methods, such that below a certain threshold, they use insertion sort, which is stable. It seems that with your implementation, this threshold is 16. In libstdc++, this threshold is defined here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1848, and it is used here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1922.

Comment: @DanielLangr cool thanks four your explanation and digging this out. Now I also understand why std::sort is stable under 17 size

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the answer is **stable_sort** Thank you @Mat